Doing k protrotype clustering in an optimised way. Can it be optimized more?
I have optimized a code that calculates the distance matrix for clustering, using the k prototype, which is used when we have numerical and categorical columns. It takes 10 seconds to run for a 1000 row dataset. But I have to run it on 90k rows. I need to optimize it, as it's taking around 15 minutes for 7k data.
I did parallel processing and masking to optimize the code. can you suggest more approaches to optimize it?
I tried to optimize it, it reduced to 10 seconds from 68 seconds. But I still want a further optimization
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from kmodes.kprototypes import euclidean_dissim, matching_dissim

def mixed_distance(a, b, categorical=None, alpha=0.01):
    cat_index = categorical
    cat_mask = np.ones_like(a, dtype=bool)
    cat_mask[cat_index] = False
    
    a_cat = a[~cat_mask].tolist()
    b_cat = b[~cat_mask].tolist()
    a_num = a[cat_mask].tolist()
    b_num = b[cat_mask].tolist()
    
    a_cat=np.array(a_cat).reshape(1,-1)
    a_num=np.array(a_num).reshape(1,-1)
    b_cat=np.array(b_cat).reshape(1,-1)
    b_num=np.array(b_num).reshape(1,-1)
    
    cat_score=matching_dissim(a_cat,b_cat)
    num_score=euclidean_dissim(a_num,b_num)
    return cat_score + num_score * alpha

def dm_prototypes(dataset, categorical=None, alpha=0.1):
    lenDataset = len(dataset)
    distance_matrix = np.zeros((lenDataset, lenDataset))

    # Define a helper function to compute distances in parallel
    def compute_distance(i, j):
        return mixed_distance(dataset[i], dataset[j], categorical=categorical, alpha=alpha)

    # Use Parallel from joblib 
    results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(
        delayed(compute_distance)(i, j)
        for i in range(lenDataset)
        for j in range(i, lenDataset)
    )

    # Fill the distance matrix using the computed distances
    idx = 0
    for i in range(lenDataset):
        for j in range(i, lenDataset):
            distance_matrix[i, j] = results[idx]
            distance_matrix[j, i] = results[idx]  # Distance matrix is symmetric
            idx += 1

    return distance_matrix

data_array=pd.DataFrame(data).values

#specify data types
data_array[:,[8,9,10]] = data_array[:,[8,9,10]].astype(str)
data_array[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]] = data_array[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]].astype(float)

distance_matrix=dm_prototypes(data_array,categorical=[8,9,10],alpha=0.1)

